# During Data Migration from Magento 1.9.4.0 to Magento 2.4 getting some warning and updated product and categories are not showing in Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.4, data-migration, data-migration-tool, warning

I want to move my data ( products , categories , sales e.t.c data ) from Magento 1.9.4.0 to Magento 2.4.

So on during the migration i have created a module so on migration getting some warning and data and when i checked the back-end after the completion the updated data is not there only the old data is there.

The warning are :

```
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Destination documents are not mapped: catalog_compare_list,email_sms_order_queue,emipro_job,magefan_blog_category,magefan_blog_category_store,magefan_blog_comment,magefan_blog_post,magefan_blog_post_category,magefan_blog_post_relatedpost,magefan_blog_post_relatedproduct,magefan_blog_post_store,magefan_blog_post_tag,magefan_blog_tag,magefan_blog_tag_store,sparsh_abandoned_cart,sparsh_abandoned_cart_email_campaign,sw_dailydeals_dailydeal,vertex_commodity_code_order_item,vertex_commodity_code_product
```

[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: adminnotification_inbox. Fields: is_amasty,expiration_date,image_url
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_creditmemo. Fields: rewardpoints_base_discount,rewardpoints_discount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_invoice. Fields: rewardpoints_base_discount,rewardpoints_discount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: tracking,rewardpoints_earn,rewardpoints_spent,rewardpoints_base_discount,rewardpoints_discount,cancellation_reason,gts_exported,mkt_order_id,preshipment_tracking,timezone_offset,phone,base_surcharge_amount,surcharge_amount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_item. Fields: rewardpoints_earn,rewardpoints_spent,rewardpoints_base_discount,rewardpoints_discount,in_stock_at_create_moment,ebay_item_id,base_surcharge_amount,surcharge_amount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_payment. Fields: epdq_transaction_id,repeat_code,custom_field_one,custom_field_two
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields: base_surcharge_amount,surcharge_amount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address_item. Fields: base_surcharge_amount,surcharge_amount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_item. Fields: base_surcharge_amount,surcharge_amount
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_payment. Fields: sagepay_token_cc_id,repeat_code,custom_field_one,custom_field_two
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: salesrule. Fields: promo_sku,promo_cats
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_compare_item. Fields: list_id
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: catalog_category_entity_text. Fields: value
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source document: catalog_product_entity_text. Fields: value
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: catalog_category_entity_text. Fields: value
[2021-09-09 12:54:36][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: catalog_product_entity_text. Fields: value

[image]

and at the end got the error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-88' for key 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entit
```

y.CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

Any idea why my updated data is not showing.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by putting some fields in ignore fields in xml file and then run this command

```
sudo bin/magento migrate:data -r -a path-of-config.xml
```

and it has imported all the data.